# Read() is reading junk data before reading actual data

Tags: c

Im having an issue using the read() function in C.

I have a file lets say fileX which has the contents:

```
Data to be outputted
```

However when I open the file and use read on it I get garbage data using the code below

```
ssize_t reader = 0;
ssize_t writer = 0;
char buffer[256];
reader = read(myFile, buffer, 256);
//check if reader is -1, if so then exit(1)
writer = write(1, buffer, 256);
//check if writer is -1, if so then exit(1)
```

The read function seems to run twice.  Once with a bunch of garbage data then followed by the actual data in the file.  Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: you should only  write what you read. change to `writer = write(1, buffer, reader);`

Comment: Your code fragment isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]) and couldn't provide your claimed behaviour.  Please provide an actual working MCVE that reproduces what you claim.  (What you've got would produce all sorts of garbage after the data in the file — and if the garbage included carriage returns, it might partially cover the genuine data.)

Comment: Why use POSIX read, write? Why not standard C fread and fwrite?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Probably because today's lesson is on using file descriptors and not file streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your buffer is filled with '\0', finished with '\0' ?
And you call write with 256 - in 3rd arg

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    const int max_size = 256;    
    char buffer[max_size] = {};
    int my_input    = open("input", O_TEXT, S_IREAD);

    ssize_t reader;
    ssize_t writer;
    reader =  read(my_input, buffer, max_size);
    if(reader != -1)
        writer = write(1, buffer, reader);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1 is the standard file descriptor number for standard output, aka STDOUT_FILENO.

Comment: Why `max_size` in `write(my_output, buffer, max_size);`?  See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268891/read-is-reading-junk-data-before-reading-actual-data#comment73606838_43268891)

Comment: Even better to make sure `reader != -1`.  [ref](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read)

Comment: @jonathan i 've forgot about it . still wonder why do people use such aincents like read write

Comment: People continue to use `read()` and `write()` because they work well in many contexts.

Comment: Note that you (almost certainly) open `output` for read only.  The `S_IWRITE` would only come into play if you had `O_CREAT` as an option.  You should probably use O_RDONLY in the first call to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (though that is usually 0, so you might not notice its absence in practice), and definitely need `O_WRONLY` (or perhaps `O_RDWR`) in the second, plus you need to think about `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` and `O_TRUNC` too.  And `O_TEXT` (and `O_BINARY`) are not POSIX terms; all files in POSIX are binary.